# Update query in Mongo Cluster

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have MongoDB cluster setup(1 Master,1 Config, 2 Shards) and imported 8 million data to collection which is sharded.
Now I have add one field collection to all documents in the collection. I am using following query which was working on single MongoDB server. But in cluster it is taking so much time and it neither  updating any documents or stopping the process.

```
db.products.update({}, {$set: {shoppingData : {"brand" : "Manufacture","title" : "Name","category" : "Cat","ean" : "EAN", "sku" : ""}}}, { multi: true })
```

Please suggest me optimized way to update all the documents in cluster.

Comment: How much data did your single server have compared to the cluster?

Comment: equal amount of data i.e 8 millions